# Inequalities (System) (solving it)

Tags: inequality, diophantine-equations, systems-of-equations

Solve the system of inequalities and indicate all the integers which are in the solution set:
\begin{align*}
3−2a&<13 \\
5a&<17 
\end{align*}

I solved it then i realized it said indicate all the integer. How do i write this?

I got $-5<a<3.4$ Please help.

Comment: Do you know the definition of integer?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

$$3-2a<13 \Rightarrow a>-5$$
$$5a<17 \Rightarrow a<3.4$$
The integer solutions are thus $\{-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3\}$